# Rellenar un treeview con un datatable c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo este datatable definido:

```
DataTable datos = new DataTable("Coordenadas");
        datos.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        datos.Columns.Add("Ciudad", typeof(string));
        datos.Columns.Add("Latitud", typeof(double));
        datos.Columns.Add("Longitud", typeof(double));

        datos.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Ciudad1", 19.0437118169261, -98.1981825828552 });
        datos.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Cuidad2", 18.6026185823842, -98.4658348560333 });
        datos.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Ciudad3", 18.1989507909863, -98.0486440658569 });
```

y me gustaria crear un treeview que se pueda visualizar asi:

Cuidades

|---Ciudad1

|---Ciudad2

|---Ciudad3

como se podria hacer?
gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta asi :

```
        DataTable datos = new DataTable("Coordenadas");
        datos.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        datos.Columns.Add("Ciudad", typeof(string));
        datos.Columns.Add("Latitud", typeof(double));
        datos.Columns.Add("Longitud", typeof(double));

        datos.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Ciudad1", 19.0437118169261, -98.1981825828552 });
        datos.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Cuidad2", 18.6026185823842, -98.4658348560333 });
        datos.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Ciudad3", 18.1989507909863, -98.0486440658569 });

        foreach (DataRow r in datos.Rows)
        {
            var node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(r["Ciudad"].ToString());
            node.Nodes.Add(r["Latitud"].ToString());
            node.Nodes.Add(r["Longitud"].ToString());
        }
```

Saludos,

Comment: Gracias Mauricio! Una ultima pregunta, como puedo hacer que las ciudades sean subnodos?

Comment: En ese caso create un nodo principal por fuera del foreach, y en lugar de añadirle nodos al treeView1, le añades nodos al nodo principal que creaste...